# Mongoose - save to mongodb works on locally(Ubuntu) but not on VPS (Ubuntu, Vultr) - no error in promise while calling save method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save, vps

I have reactjs + nodejs - kind of CRUD app on mongodb.
While perfroming "save" via mongoose - it works fine in local laptop (Ubuntu) but same code (save method) does not return error but not even creating database when I try on VPS.

Any links.. no clue - I could get in pm2 logs(as it says MongoDB connection is fine)

Br
D